# EditText and Spinner look different when inflated programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am making a screen for the addition of a contact. 
For the phones and phone types I have an `EditText` and a `Spinner` type and these are included in a `LinearLayout`

If I add my Layout on a xml and inflate it to reuse it as many times as required, the result is quite different.

```
   LinearLayout phoneLayout= (LinearLayout) inflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.add_contact_phone_element, container, false);
```

Specifically, there are 3 differences I need help with how to solve them, and if possible why they happen.

On the first image you can see one field how it seems at the original xml and how it looks when added programmatically from another xml.

1. The text color is white at the inflated field
2. Spinner color is white at the inflated field when non expanded
3. When expanded, the spinner is different from the original (photos 2,3). On the expanded, its black background with white color on the text.

What is wrong and they appear so differently?

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can see the code here. The same code is included at the original xml, its just copy-pasted to another so it can be reused.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/phone1Cont"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/phoneImg"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/InputPhoneValue"
    style="@style/Dialog.Contact.AddText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:hint="@string/JournalDetailViewPhoneLabel"
    android:inputType="phone" />


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/phoneTypeSpinner"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/InputPhoneValue"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
    android:entries="@array/phone_type" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How do you inflate programmatically the components?

Comment: i will edit on the post so it can be seen

Comment: Just add theme programmatically in spinner.